# Deploying war to tomcat using chef

Tags: tomcat, chef-infra

I'm attempting to automate deploying a war to tomcat using the chef system.

I've have a war which previously I would either upload using the manager servlet or just copy to /var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/, but that doesn't appear to be the chef way.

I've got the following in my recipe:

```
application "app" do
    path "/usr/local/app"
    repository "/root/dist/app-0.1.war"
    scm_provider Chef::Provider::File::Deploy
    tomcat
end
```

Which runs but doesn't work -- Catalina.out is giving

```
May 5, 2013 2:32:31 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
SEVERE: Error deploying configuration descriptor app.xml
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /etc/tomcat6/Catalina/localhost/app.xml (No such file or directory)
```

Edit: Right now I've got a workaround in place which manually places the war into the webapps directory, blows away the prior exploded directory and restarts tomcat.  It seems, though, that I'm working too hard and inelegantly for what ought to be simple.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Why don't you keep doing the same as before?
Use the `remote_file` [resource](http://docs.opscode.com/resource_remote_file.html) and place the `war` in `/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/`.

Comment: Is that idiomatic chef?  It seems really hackish, and it's not using `application_java` at all.

Comment: True, it's not using `application_java`. It just seems like you have a more basic requirement that can be easily solved using one of Chef's primitives. If you need greater customisation, then by all means go the hard way as it's going to pay off in the long run. If all you need is to place the file in Tomcat's war dir, then you're probably better off not complicating things too much. :)

Comment: you ned to include cookbook [application_java](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/application_java) as a dependency of your cookbook *app* in `metadata.rb`, which will bring dependencies like `java` and `tomcat`.